# Windows 8 desktop stuck in "Repairing disk errors"

Tags: windows-8

While working on a project I was suddenly informed by windows 8 that it ABSOLUTELY just HAD to reset to install updates, and I had 15 minutes to comply. So I save my stuff and click "update and restart". My computer starts installing updates, gets to 30%, then shuts down. I hear 2 quick beeps from the motherboard speaker and it starts up again showing "repairing disk errors", along with a message informing me that this could take an hour. This has now been about 4 hours ago. The disk activity lights have long since stopped blinking and it's sitting there keeping my files hostage. What should I do to repair this? The computer is less then a year old with a hard disk with about 1.8TB space. The motherboard is an Asus Sabertooth Z77. I haven't touched anything on my PC and it's currently still on showing the same image.

Status Update:

Restarting the system brought me to auto repair, it failed and brought me to a repair menu. Can't boot in safe mode or use any restore option. Command prompt shows the entire C: drive to be renamed to the D: drive and I'm currently running chkdsk /r/f on it.

Comment: The drive letter change is temporary, but looks like it's time for you to buy a new HDD.

Comment: I haven't had a single issue with this HDD before and I'm pretty sure it's even still under warranty.

Comment: Oh well, then get it exchanged. Personally I don't trust any HDD with bad sectors with my critical data, no matter if it's got 5 of them or 50.

Comment: I'll contact the shop that assembled my PC, this is waaaaaaaaay over just 50 bad sectors.

Comment: If you need to get important data off it before contacting the shop look into GNU ddrescue (there are questions about this already).

Comment: Moral of the story: git commit early, git commit often

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to perform a startup repair using Windows 8 bootable DVD or USB drive and check if that helps.

- Insert the installation DVD or USB and boot Windows 8 from it.
- In the `Windows setup` page select the `language to install`, `Time and currency format` and the `keyboard or input method` and click on `next`.
- Click on `Repair your computer` and select `Troubleshoot`.
- Click on `Advanced options` and select `Automatic Repair` and select the operating system.

---

In screen Advanced Startup Options, click on `Command Prompt`.

Type `chkdsk d: /r/f` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Where:

- `/r` : Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information.
- `/f` : Fixes errors on the disk.

When chkdsk is finished, restart your computer and check if the error persists.

Comment: After 5 hours of running chkdsk and fixing thousands of corrupted sectors, the problem persists.

Comment: Logs say: "root cause found: failed to find OS loader"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to reset BIOS and also access safe mode and perform system restore in safe mode as well as if that does not help perform hard reset on your PC to resolve this issue.